Read from Release Pipeline Variable Groups
Anyone has an idea how to successfully read from variable groups in Azure DevOps ?
In a release pipeline, in a PowerShell Script (though I've tried the same in an Azure PowerShell Script), I'm trying this command:
az pipelines variable-group variable list --org https://dev.azure.com/{{ orgName }}/ --project {{ projectName}} --group-id {{ groupID }} --output table
It complains that I'm not logged in: ERROR: Before you can run Azure DevOps commands, you need to run the login command(az login if using AAD/MSA identity else az devops login if using PAT token) to setup credentials.  Please see https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth for more information.
I try running this command before that:
echo $(System.AccessToken) | az devops login --org https://dev.azure.com/{{ orgName }}/
It complains the provided access token isn't valid: ERROR: Failed to authenticate using the supplied token.
Yes, I checked "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token".

As mentioned in this MS Document, you need to use
az devops login --org with PAT tokens. It won't work with OAuth tokens. You can directly login with user account by running az login as mentioned here @FrancescoGhigo

@VinayB I see, at least that explains it ! I've been asked not to use PAT's in the past because they'd be linked to a single user (me). Is this command the only way to read from Variable Groups in a release or it can be done some other way ?
Anyway, the documentation itself suggested the line of code I mentioned (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows, in the "From a variable" section)

If you plan to use in in a YAML pipeline or a classical build/release you don't need to read it using a script - just reference the variable group and access its values using $(foo) or $(var) as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group

@RuiJarimba that works, but the issue is that I have a set of keys (e.g. "foo", "bar") that may change (e.g. "oof", "rab"), so I need to access $(foo) and $(bar) in the first case and $(oof) and $(rab) in the second. I was hoping to get a JSON of the variable group and access the variables I need through that.

@FrancescoGhigo that's not the way you should be using variable groups IMO - keys (aka variable names) should not be dynamic. But it's easy enough to use a workaround without using Azure DevOps CLI.

@RuiJarimba wish I didn't have to, but that's what the task's about :( Thanks for the insight, though !

@FrancescoGhigo how exactly do you know which variable group to use? If I understood correctly, you're using (classical) release pipelines so the variable groups need to be linked manually. Are you using these variables directly in the release or in a task group?

If you use System.AccessToken for 'az devops login', in the security hub of the variable group, ensure you have assigned the two build identities with the Reader role at least.

Project Collection Build Service ({Org Name})
{Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})


I can see the same error message "ERROR: Failed to authenticate using the supplied token." When using PowerShell task to run the commands. However, it does not affect the command to output the correct result.

If you do not want to see the error message "ERROR: Failed to authenticate using the supplied token.", you can consider using Bash task to run the commands.


EDIT:
Within the same organization, if the variable group is in a different project than the pipeline, you need to go to "Project Settings" (and "Organization Settings") > "Settings" under "Pipelines" to ensure the following options are turned off.

Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines
Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines




it's great that you get the result anyway, because I get both the errors about the failed authentication and the need to run the login commands (as mentioned in the post), so no table for me. I suppose you have some other settings set right that allow you to run that. Anywho, I checked the security you mentioned and both the entries were already there and have "Reader" assigned, so that's unfortunately not it :(

@FrancescoGhigo, I have updated my above answer with more information (see EDIT). Check and try with it.

It's also off, so that's not it. We're discussing how to proceed, might have to discard this option for lack of time to further analyse this, but thanks for your insight !

@FrancescoGhigo, How about try to create a new pipeline to see if it still has the problem?

@FrancescoGhigo, Would like to list the variables from group via calling the REST API "Variablegroups - Get" in the script?
